# PHP/Laravel, url with multiples arguments

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm building a Laravel app, and I need to use an URL that looks like that :

```
/api/ads?page=Actuel&formatsQuery[]=side&formatsQuery[]=leaderboard&deviceQuery=mobile
```

I have 3 parameters (page, formatsQuery (as an array), and deviceQuery).

Do you now how to hold his in routing and controller in order to have the correct value inside the controller's fonction?

I tried this :
routes/api.php

```js
//request to get ads for given parameters
Route::get('/ads', [MediaController::class, 'findAds']);
```

and this (MediaController.php) :

```js
public function findAds($page, $formatsQuery, $deviceQuery) {
      echo $page;
      if(sizeof($formatsQuery) <= 0 || sizeof($formatsQuery) > 3){
        return $this->unvalidParametersError();
      }
      //transform format to position depending on deviceQuery
      $position = [];
      $res = [];
      foreach ($formatsQuery as $format) {
        $res =  Media::where('position', $format)->inRandomOrder()->first()->union($res);
      }
      echo $res;
      return $res;
    }
```

then I test it with this :

```js
public function test_findAds()
    {
      $ads = Ad::factory()
            ->has(Media::factory()->count(3), 'medias')
            ->count(3)->create();
      $response = $this->get('/api/ads?page=Actuel&formatsQuery[]=side&formatsQuery[]=leaderboard&deviceQuery=mobile');

      $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input), it is pretty explanatory... In your case, you are using a `get` to send that URL (you should be doing so), so you simply do `$request->input('page')`, and it should return `Actuel`. And do that with all your input. For arrays, don't write `[]` after the name...

Comment: Have you tried something? add your code. You can read the query using the Request object in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `GET` request to fetch your data. `GET` request is a type of request that you send parameters in URL using `?` after URL and separating parameters with `&`. You can find out more about HTTP methods [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

In laravel using request parameters is so simple. First of all you need to add `Request $request` to your method prototype like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function findAds(Request $request)
```

Then you can simply use `$request->parameter` to get the values. So you need to change your code like this:

```
public function findAds(Request $request){
    $page = $request->page;
    $formatsQuery = $request->formatsQuery;
    $deviceQuery = $request->deviceQuery;

    // Your code
}
```

And as @matiaslauriti mentioned in the comments you don't need to put `[]` after `formatsQuery[]` to send an array in `GET` request. Using the same key more than one time automatically makes an array for you.